# express $1+\frac{(-1)^n}{n}$ in terms of other functions

Tags: calculus, calculator

Suppose a sequence $(a_n)$ is defined as $a_n=1+\frac{(-1)^n}{n}$ for $n \geq 1$. I want to plot these points on a [desmos graphing calculator](https://www.desmos.com/calculator).

However, the calculator does not accept $(-1)^n$, as it does not display any graph after I key in.

Question: Is it possible to express $a_n$ in terms of modulus  or other functions so that it can be shown in the calculator?

Comment: A widely used continuous alternative to $(-1)^n$ is $\cos( \pi n)$. Try to plot $1+ \frac{\cos (\pi x)}{x}$

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Replace $n$ by $\lfloor x\rfloor$ in both places and you'll get the graph you want, I think.

Comment: Does not give the same graph.

Comment: User170039 changed "floor" to $\lfloor x \rfloor$.  This is not the notation that Desmos uses. You broke my answer.  @A---B, The same graph as _what_?

Comment: Same graph as $y = 1 + (-1)^n/n$ - wofram alpha.